# How can I check the system version of Android?

Tags: android, version, system

Does anyone know how can I check the system version (e.g. `1.0`, `2.2`, etc.) programatically?

Comment: is there shortcut (code snippet or live template) to add this check in android studio

Answer (score 462, accepted):

Check [`android.os.Build.VERSION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html).

> - `CODENAME`: The current development codename, or the string "REL" if this is a release build.
> - `INCREMENTAL`:  The internal value used by the underlying source control to represent this build.
> - `RELEASE`:  The user-visible version string.

Comment: any examples on how to use it?

Comment: The hard part about this is that SDK_INT has been defined in API Level 4 and using it fails on 1-3. Does anybody know how to nicely deal with that?

Comment: SDK is available since API 1, also INCREMENTAL is available for all versions.

Comment: Build.VERSION.RELEASE is a String, therefore you can use this String however you like.

Comment: Don't worry, not even cavemen are using android APIs 1-3 today. @Zordid

Comment: Example output is: `BASE_OS = `, `CODENAME = REL`, `INCREMENTAL = 3311891731`, `RELEASE = 9`. Usable one is only `RELEASE` at my side.

Answer (score 926):

Example how to use it:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
     // only for gingerbread and newer versions
}
```

Comment: I totally ignore any older version than Eclair (7), Android 2.1 and very soon we stop support for the 2.1 also. But you can use the SDK instead of SDK_INT.

Comment: SDK was depecated in API level 4. Use SDK_INT instead.

Comment: I have a question: if it is running on a system older than GINGERBREAD, then we can not get android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD, will the app crash?

Comment: No, because GINGERBREAD will by replaced by just the number during the java build. It is only necessary to use bigger compile version of Android.

Comment: I get `Unresolved reference: Manifest` for some reason

Answer (score 134):

[Build.Version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) is the place go to for this data. Here is a code snippet for how to format it.

```
public String getAndroidVersion() {
    String release = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    int sdkVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    return "Android SDK: " + sdkVersion + " (" + release +")";
}
```

Looks like this "Android SDK: 19 (4.4.4)"

Answer (score 86):

For checking device version which is greater than or equal to Marshmallow ,use this code.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

    }
```

for ckecking others just change the VERSION_CODES like,
K for kitkat,
L for loolipop
N for Nougat and so on...

Answer (score 69):

```
Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

That will give you the actual numbers of your version; aka 2.3.3 or 2.2.
The problem with using Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is if you have a rooted phone or custom rom, you could have a none standard OS (aka my android is running 2.3.5) and that will return a null when using Build.VERSION.SDK_INT so Build.VERSION.RELEASE will work no matter what!

Comment: From SDK: "The user-visible version string. E.g., "1.0" or "3.4b5"." .... "3.4b5" how can I determine which version number is it ?

Comment: The whole answer 2.3.3 is the version number, or 2.2, or 2.3.5 (custom rom in my case).  That is the OS Version number as a whole.

Comment: It returns the same thing Menu >> Settings >> About Phone.  It should be labeled Firmware Version or something to that affect.

Comment: How the hell could an int return a null? SDK_INT is a primitive int.

Answer (score 50):

You can find out the Android version looking at [`Build.VERSION`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html).

The documentation recommends you check [`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) against the values in [`Build.VERSION_CODES`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html).

This is fine as long as you realise that `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` was only introduced in API Level 4, which is to say Android 1.6 (Donut).  So this won't affect you, but if you did want your app to run on Android 1.5 or earlier then you would have to use the deprecated [`Build.VERSION.SDK`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK) instead.

Answer (score 37):

I can't comment on the answers, but there is a huge mistake in Kaushik's answer:
SDK_INT is not the same as system version but actually refers to API Level.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
    //this code will be executed on devices running ICS or later
}
```

The value `Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH` equals 14.
14 is the API level of Ice Cream Sandwich, while the system version is 4.0. So if you write 4.0, your code will be executed on all devices starting from Donut, because 4 is the API level of Donut (`Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT` equals 4).

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 4.0){
    //this code will be executed on devices running on DONUT (NOT ICS) or later
}
```

This example is a reason why using 'magic number' is a bad habit.

Comment: Actually, Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is the API level, not the version code. So the proper line would be `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15){`

Comment: What if i told you version code is the same as API level and the SDK_INT of ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH is 14 not 15? @erdomester

Answer (score 29):

Be aware that [Build.VERSION.SDK_INT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) isn't reliable, it's mentioned by @Falcon165o and recently I ran into that one too.

So to get the String data (based on [Android version list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history)) of currently installed android, I made a code like this:

**Java**

```
//Current Android version data
public static String currentVersion(){
    double release=Double.parseDouble(Build.VERSION.RELEASE.replaceAll("(\\d+[.]\\d+)(.*)","$1"));
    String codeName="Unsupported";//below Jelly Bean
    if(release >= 4.1 && release < 4.4) codeName = "Jelly Bean";
    else if(release < 5)   codeName="Kit Kat";
    else if(release < 6)   codeName="Lollipop";
    else if(release < 7)   codeName="Marshmallow";
    else if(release < 8)   codeName="Nougat";
    else if(release < 9)   codeName="Oreo";
    else if(release < 10)  codeName="Pie";
    else if(release >= 10) codeName="Android "+((int)release);//since API 29 no more candy code names
    return codeName+" v"+release+", API Level: "+Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
fun currentVersion(): String {
    val release = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(java.lang.String(Build.VERSION.RELEASE).replaceAll("(\\d+[.]\\d+)(.*)", "$1"))
    var codeName = "Unsupported"//below Jelly Bean
    if (release >= 4.1 && release < 4.4)  codeName = "Jelly Bean"
    else if (release < 5)   codeName = "Kit Kat"
    else if (release < 6)   codeName = "Lollipop"
    else if (release < 7)   codeName = "Marshmallow"
    else if (release < 8)   codeName = "Nougat"
    else if (release < 9)   codeName = "Oreo"
    else if (release < 10)  codeName = "Pie"
    else if (release >= 10) codeName = "Android "+(release.toInt())//since API 29 no more candy code names
    return codeName + " v" + release + ", API Level: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
}
```

Example of an output it produce:

> Marshmallow v6.0, API Level: 23

Comment: This code crash at Double.parseDouble(Build.VERSION.RELEASE) when the release contains more than one dot. For example 7.1.1

Comment: @MiklósKeresztes Thank you for informative comment - I've fixed my answer.

Answer (score 27):

For example, a feature only works for api21 up the following we fix bugs in api21 down

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    //only api 21 above
    }else{
   //only api 21 down
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= ApiHelper.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
//do anything you  like.
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 6):

Use This method:

```
 public static String getAndroidVersion() {
        String versionName = "";

        try {
             versionName = String.valueOf(Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return versionName;
    }
```

Comment: How will this help?

Answer (score 5):

use this class

```
import android.os.Build;

/**
 * Created by MOMANI on 2016/04/14.
 */
public class AndroidVersionUtil {
    public static int getApiVersion() {
        return android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    }

    public static boolean isApiVersionGraterOrEqual(int thisVersion) {
        return android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= thisVersion;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you have `bash` on your android device, you can use this bash function :

```
function androidCodeName {
    androidRelease=$(getprop ro.build.version.release)
    androidCodeName=$(getprop ro.build.version.codename)

    # Time "androidRelease" x10 to test it as an integer
    case $androidRelease in
        [0-9].[0-9]|[0-9].[0-9].|[0-9].[0-9].[0-9])  androidRelease=$(echo $androidRelease | cut -d. -f1-2 | tr -d .);;
        [0-9].) androidRelease=$(echo $androidRelease | sed 's/\./0/');;
        [0-9]) androidRelease+="0";;
    esac

    [ -n "$androidRelease" ] && [ $androidCodeName = REL ] && {
    # Do not use "androidCodeName" when it equals to "REL" but infer it from "androidRelease"
        androidCodeName=""
        case $androidRelease in
        10) androidCodeName+=NoCodename;;
        11) androidCodeName+="Petit Four";;
        15) androidCodeName+=Cupcake;;
        20|21) androidCodeName+=Eclair;;
        22) androidCodeName+=FroYo;;
        23) androidCodeName+=Gingerbread;;
        30|31|32) androidCodeName+=Honeycomb;;
        40) androidCodeName+="Ice Cream Sandwich";;
        41|42|43) androidCodeName+="Jelly Bean";;
        44) androidCodeName+=KitKat;;
        50|51) androidCodeName+=Lollipop;;
        60) androidCodeName+=Marshmallow;;
        70|71) androidCodeName+=Nougat;;
        80|81) androidCodeName+=Oreo;;
        90) androidCodeName+=Pie;;
        100) androidCodeName+=ToBeReleased;;
        *) androidCodeName=unknown;;
        esac
    }
    echo $androidCodeName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Android documentation:

> Build.VERSION.RELEASE – "The user-visible version string. E.g., "1.0"
> or "3.4b5" or "bananas""

In order to get a plain Android version (2.3, 5.1, 12.0, etc) I use this function:

```
private fun getVersion(): Float {
    val release = Build.VERSION.RELEASE
    val parsedVersion = "\\d+(\\.\\d+)?".toRegex()
        .find(release)?.value
    if (parsedVersion.isNullOrBlank()) return 0f
    return try {
        parsedVersion.toFloat()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        0f
    }
}
```