# How to check Android version in code

Tags: android, android-version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android get version of system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365/android-get-version-of-system)

How to Identify current android device OS from code?
So from my application i need to know the current device version (2 is 5 or 2.01 6 Donut - 2.01 or 2.2  7 Eclair)??

Because if it's 2.2 i want to use c2dm, but if it's lower than 2.2 than i will not perform this action.
But i want my application can be use from Android 1.6.

Thanks