# To get android os version at run time

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android get version of system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365/android-get-version-of-system)

I have to detect current android os version at run time. how can i do this if any one know please help me.

Comment: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014117/how-can-i-check-in-code-the-android-version-like-1-5-or-1-6
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365/android-get-version-of-system
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506792/android-api-version-programmatically
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882883/android-sdk-version
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322514/how-to-check-android-version-in-code