# How to get the android device build number

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check Android version in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322514/how-to-check-android-version-in-code)

I have a requirement to get the Build number of the android device programatically.

Can any one suggest how to get this information..??

I tried with "Build" and "TelephonyManager" but no luck.

pl. let me know if I miss some thing.

thanks.

Comment: What does `android.os.Build.VERSION` give you?

Comment: this will return the android version.

Comment: So what are you referring to when you say "Build number"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for "build number" you mean the IMEI number, for example, then check about **TelephonyManager.getDeviceSoftwareVersion()**. However, I refer you to this link http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ab7bd52d01b4a4d6