# Getting device os version in Android programmatically

Tags: java, android

How can I get the current android device version (1.5, 1.6, 2.0, etc.) programmatically? i.e I have installed my apk on an Android 2.2 device. I need to get the device version (android emulator version in which my application is currently running ).

Comment: See duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365/android-get-version-of-system

Answer (score 107):

Something like these:

```java
String myVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE; // e.g. myVersion := "1.6"
int sdkVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT; // e.g. sdkVersion := 8;
```

You can retrieve all SDK codes from `Build.VERSION_CODES`

Comment: What is recommended to use for representing os, Build.VERSION.RELEASE or Build.VERSION.SDK.INT? Both get the job done, but is there an industry standard or more popular choice?

Comment: @portfoliobuilder `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is good at comparisons between versions (less than/greater than, etc.)

Comment: s described in the android documentation, the SDK level (integer) the phone is running is available in:

android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

The enum corresponding to this int is in the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES class.

Code example:

int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
    // Do something for froyo and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before froyo
}

Comment: Edit: This SDK_INT is available since Donut (android 1.6 / API4) so make sure your application is not retro-compatible with Cupcake (android 1.5 / API3) when you use it or your application will crash (thanks to Programmer Bruce for the precision).

Answer (score 14):

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    // Do something for lollipop and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before lollipop
}
```

By this code we can execute separate code for Pre Lollipop devices.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see the firmware version number then you can use

```
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
```

But if you want firmware version name then you should use something like this

```
Build.VERSION_CODES
```

Answer (score 5):

Try This,

```
    String deviceOs = android.os.Build.VERSION;
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Build.VERSION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) version class. Depending on what you want to do, you might want to use the `RELEASE` or `SDK_INT` attribute.