# Fast scroll thumb disappears while scrolling AlphabetIndexer

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with `fastScrollAlwaysVisible` and `fastScrollEnabled` both set to `true`. After implementing `SectionIndexer` to my `Adapter` and an `AlphabetIndexer`, my `fast scroll thumb` will disappear while I scroll, then reappear once I reach the top or bottom of the list. I'm pretty clueless about why this happens. I haven't experienced it before.

Everything below works as far as `AlphabetIndexer` is concerned. My question is why does my fast scroll thumb disappear while I scroll and how can I stop it from disappearing?

Whether or not the `fast scroll` is *always* visible doesn't matter. Whenever the `fast scroll` is visible, the `fast scroll thumb` is not there, it's simply gone and that's my problem. Also, when I remove the `AlphabetIndexer` the `fast scroll thumb` works like I intend for it to. Everything works successfully in an `Activity`, but when I load my `ListView` in a `Fragment` things end up like I explain.

This is my `Adapter` for my `ListView`:

```
private class AlbumsAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements
        SectionIndexer {

private AlphabetIndexer mIndexer;

// I have to override this because I'm using a `LoaderManager`
@Override
    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {

        if (cursor != null) {
            mIndexer = new MusicAlphabetIndexer(cursor, mAlbumIdx,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.fast_scroll_alphabet));
        }
        return super.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        return mIndexer.getSections();
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        return mIndexer.getPositionForSection(section);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

`MusicAlphabetIndexer` helps sort through music correctly:

```
class MusicAlphabetIndexer extends AlphabetIndexer {

public MusicAlphabetIndexer(Cursor cursor, int sortedColumnIndex,
        CharSequence alphabet) {
    super(cursor, sortedColumnIndex, alphabet);
}

@Override
protected int compare(String word, String letter) {
    String wordKey = MediaStore.Audio.keyFor(word);
    String letterKey = MediaStore.Audio.keyFor(letter);
    if (wordKey.startsWith(letter)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return wordKey.compareTo(letterKey);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am doing something similiar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224233/alphabetindexer-with-custom-adapter-managed-by-loadermanager

Comment: I took at your post and didn't see anything wrong. My `SectionIndexer` works and doesn't show as you scroll and it seems you're having the opposite problem, weird. I'm starting to think `Fragments` are the culprit, but I'm unsure how right now. I think they are because my `SectionIndexer` works in a `ListActivity`.

Comment: I'll try to see if I can recreate your issues.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue with fast scroller's thumb icon. I was investigating Android source code and found a commit which introduced this problem and other (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException). I built even Android system without this commit and it worked then.

I submitted the issue in June: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33293
When I'm reading it know I see I could describe the issue better :)

This is the commit which is making problems: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/32c3a6929af9d63de3bf45a61be6e1a4bde136d3

Unfortunately I haven't found any solution, except revert the commit, and I left it.
I hope someone will find how to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected that it was a framework bug. I've also seen other apps in the Play Store experience the same thing. I"m glad you posted this.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have both `fastScrollEnabled` and [`fastScrollAlwaysVisible`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollAlwaysVisible%28boolean%29) set to `true`? There is no `fastScrollAlwaysEnabled` attribute of a `ListView`, so I'm thinking maybe you just have `fastScrollEnabled` set to true but `fastScrollAlwaysVisible` is set to its default value, which is `false`.

Comment: Oh, wow. That's actually a typo. I did mean `fastScrollAlwaysVisible`. I also have `fastScrollEnabled` set to true. I actually updated my OP a little more. Thanks for commenting, I never would have noticed I made a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion <= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
    // Do something for froyo and above versions
    list.setFastScrollEnabled(true);


} else if(currentapiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    // do something for phones running an SDK before froyo
    list.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    list.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Wow, [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30370154/1677912) [code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29958384/1677912) [gets](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34332188/1677912) [around](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3940823/1677912)! Suggest you provide attribution for code you've found. (The basic structure is from docs, right?)

Comment: [setFastScrollAlwaysVisible](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(boolean)) -> Set whether or not the fast scroller should always be shown in place of the standard scroll bars.

Answer (score -2):

Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AlphabetIndexer;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SectionIndexer;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class TestAct extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ListView test_listView;
    Cursor myCursor;
    String[] proj;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_app_test);

        TestDummyData cTestDummyData = new TestDummyData(
                getApplicationContext());
        cTestDummyData.open();
        cTestDummyData.insertRandomNames();
        myCursor = cTestDummyData.fetchAllData();

        test_listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pager_list_test);
        test_listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

        test_listView.setAdapter(

        new MyCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myCursor,
                new String[] { TestDummyData.KEY_NAME },// names
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 })

        );

        cTestDummyData.close();

    }

    class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer {

        AlphabetIndexer alphaIndexer;

        // HashMap<String, Integer> alphaIndexer;
        // String[] sections;
        public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);

            alphaIndexer = new AlphabetIndexer(c,
                    myCursor.getColumnIndex(TestDummyData.KEY_NAME),
                    " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
            // ======optional way to get alphaindexer from data
            // alphaIndexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            // int size = items.size();
            //
            // for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            // String s = items.get(x);
            //
            // String ch = s.substring(0, 1);
            //
            // ch = ch.toUpperCase();
            //
            // alphaIndexer.put(ch, x);
            // }
            //
            // Set<String> sectionLetters = alphaIndexer.keySet();
            //
            // ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(
            // sectionLetters);
            //
            // Collections.sort(sectionList);
            //
            // sections = new String[sectionList.size()];
            //
            // sectionList.toArray(sections);

        }

        @Override
        public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return alphaIndexer.getPositionForSection(section);
        }

        @Override
        public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return alphaIndexer.getSectionForPosition(position);
        }

        @Override
        public Object[] getSections() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return alphaIndexer.getSections();
        }

    }

}
```

Class To use Dummy Data For listing

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestDummyData {

    static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

    private static final String DB_NAME = "tutorial";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "names";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME
            + " (" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_NAME
            + " varchar not null);";

    private Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public TestDummyData(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.v("DBUTIL", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion
                    + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public void open() {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public void insertRandomNames() {
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME);
        String s = "ANDROIDDEVELOPER";
        Random r = new Random();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            values.clear();
            values.put(KEY_NAME, s.substring(r.nextInt(s.length())));
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        }
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllData() {
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY "
                + KEY_NAME + " ASC", null);
    }

}
```

the above class is dummy data clss for common task...
list_app_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<ListView 
android:id="@+id/pager_list_test" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

you have just give test_listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
gvn ans whter i cn understand from ur quest.

Comment: This isn't helpful. I know how to implement a `SectionIndexer`. What I don't know is why the fast scroll thumb disappears while I scroll.

Comment: This is possibly the least useful answer I've ever come across.