# How to find the Android version name programmatically?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I write code for finding the Android version like this

```
String version=Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

by using this code I am get the version number but I want version name.
how to get the version name?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As suggested earlier, reflection seems to be the key to this question. The StringBuilder and extra formatting is not required, it was added only to illustrate usage.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
...

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("android : ").append(Build.VERSION.RELEASE);

Field[] fields = Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    String fieldName = field.getName();
    int fieldValue = -1;

    try {
        fieldValue = field.getInt(new Object());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (fieldValue == Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
        builder.append(" : ").append(fieldName).append(" : ");
        builder.append("sdk=").append(fieldValue);
    }
}

Log.d(LOG_TAG, "OS: " + builder.toString());
```

On my 4.1 emulator, I get this output:

```
D/MainActivity( 1551): OS: android : 4.1.1 : JELLY_BEAN : sdk=16
```

Enjoy!

Comment: It would be simpler, and safer, to use your own static array of the names and look it up by index.

Comment: A static array could be ideal for an app that could be updated regularly for every release, but for projects that may not be updated for many releases of Android, this might still be a preferred solution.

Comment: Its returning just P, instead of Pie.

Answer (score 22):

After **API 28 (Android Pie)**, **Build.VERSION_CODES** were **changed** some fields.

So, if you using:

```
Field[] fields = Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields();
String osName = fields[Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + 1].getName();
```

will cause your app **CRASH immediately** because of **Out Of Range Exception**.

The solution for all API level is:

```
Field[] fields = Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields();
String codeName = "UNKNOWN";
for (Field field : fields) {
    try {
        if (field.getInt(Build.VERSION_CODES.class) == Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
            codeName = field.getName();
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Or in Kotlin with Java 8's style:

```
val fields = Build.VERSION_CODES::class.java.fields
var codeName = "UNKNOWN"
fields.filter { it.getInt(Build.VERSION_CODES::class) == Build.VERSION.SDK_INT }
      .forEach { codeName = it.name }
```

Or shorter version (thanks @datiKaa)

```
val fields = Build.VERSION_CODES::class.java.fields
val codeName fields.firstOrNull { it.getInt(Build.VERSION_CODES::class) == Build.VERSION.SDK_INT }?.name ?: "UNKNOWN"
```

Comment: Your solution is simply the best because the fields arrangement has changed since API 28.

Comment: Instead of looping on a filtered list, you can go for firstOrNull.


`val fields = Build.VERSION_CODES::class.java.fields
            val codeName fields.firstOrNull { it.getInt(Build.VERSION_CODES::class) == Build.VERSION.SDK_INT }?.name ?: "UNKNOWN"`

Comment: Good Answer! This code is run by api 29. :)

Answer (score 19):

Optimized code, this will work:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

Field[] fields = Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields();
String osName = fields[Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + 1].getName();
Log.d("Android OsName:",osName);
```

Comment: Just an FYI: For Android 8.1, this yields: O_MR1

Comment: Yes, Android returns the name depends on defined variables https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

Comment: This got me in trouble recently because the '+ 1' made it run off the end of the fields array.  I don't understand the reasoning here.  I ended up adding a check to see if SDK_INT + 1 was too large.  If it was, I use the last entry in 'fields', but I really don't know if that is the best thing to do.  There's more about this in one of the comments below.

Comment: Not safe now. May cause crashes. We can use build an string array / Map and manually map version number / with string names.

Answer (score 5):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html contains fields that have the name you're looking for.
So you could use reflexion to find which field corresponds to the "version" value.

Why do you want the name ?

Comment: client requirement is to get the version number and version name of his mobile

Comment: Then best is probably to send the Build.VERSION.SDK_INT to your server and then have a mapping from that int to the names you want to give to your clients.

Comment: I just gave you one and so did the other answer : use android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT to get a number then find which field in android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES has that value via reflexion. The name of the field is what you're looking for

Answer (score 4):

You will get the information from these

```
android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES 

android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
```

More information can be had from this link:

[Retrieving Android API version programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out:

```
// Names taken from android.os.build.VERSION_CODES
String[] mapper = new String[] {
    "ANDROID BASE", "ANDROID BASE 1.1", "CUPCAKE", "DONUT",
    "ECLAIR", "ECLAIR_0_1", "ECLAIR_MR1", "FROYO", "GINGERBREAD",
    "GINGERBREAD_MR1", "HONEYCOMB", "HONEYCOMB_MR1", "HONEYCOMB_MR2",
    "ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH", "ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1", "JELLY_BEAN"
};
int index = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT - 1;
String versionName = index < mapper.length? mapper[index] : "UNKNOWN_VERSION"; // > JELLY_BEAN)
```

Be aware that this solution will only work as far as the version codes keep being incremented by one, and you will have to update the list with each new android version (if being accurate is important).

Comment: So what, each and every new Android version you'll have to update this array, weak.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the android documentation, the SDK level (integer) the phone is running is available in:

android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

The enum corresponding to this int is in the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES class.

Code example:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
    // Do something for froyo and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before froyo
}
```

Edit: This SDK_INT is available since Donut (android 1.6 / API4) so make sure your application is not retro-compatible with Cupcake (android 1.5 / API3) when you use it or your application will crash (thanks to Programmer Bruce for the precision).

Answer (score 1):

I've applied the solution above, but wasn't quite happy with "O" and "N" as version names, so I made some changes. Hope it will be useful for others too

```
    /**
 * Gets the version name from version code. Note! Needs to be updated
 * when new versions arrive, or will return a single letter. Like Android 8.0 - Oreo
 * yields "O" as a version name.
 * @return version name of device's OS
 */
private static String getOsVersionName() {
    Field[] fields = Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields();
    String name =  fields[Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + 1].getName();

    if(name.equals("O")) name = "Oreo";
    if(name.equals("N")) name = "Nougat";
    if(name.equals("M")) name = "Marshmallow";

    if(name.startsWith("O_")) name = "Oreo++";
    if(name.startsWith("N_")) name = "Nougat++";

    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**A beginner level friendly solution.**
I use version codes, because they are better and less confusing than code-names. For ex. jelly bean, oreo, lollipop etc. have different version codes under single codename. **Anyway, You can replace version codes with codenames.**

```
 var androidVersion = ""
    androidVersion = when (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT){
        16 -> "Android 4.1"
        17 -> "Android 4.2"
        18 -> "Android 4.3"
        19 -> "Android 4.4"
        21 -> "Android 5.0"
        22 -> "Android 5.1"
        23 -> "Android 6.0"
        24 -> "Android 7.0"
        25 -> "Android 7.1"
        26 -> "Android 8.0"
        27 -> "Android 8.1"
        28 -> "Android 9"
        29 -> "Android 10"
        else -> "API " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is not working when I have tried in emulator running on API 19.

So I come up with an hybrid answer of "Nacho Coloma" and "Kevin Grant"

```
String osName="";
Field[] fields = Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    String fieldName = field.getName();
    int fieldValue = -1;

    try {
        fieldValue = field.getInt(new Object());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (fieldValue == Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
        osName=fieldName; break;
    }
}
if(osName.isEmpty()) {
    String[] mapper = new String[]{
            "ANDROID BASE", "ANDROID BASE 1.1", "CUPCAKE", "DONUT",
            "ECLAIR", "ECLAIR_0_1", "ECLAIR_MR1", "FROYO",
            "GINGERBREAD", "GINGERBREAD_MR1", "HONEYCOMB", "HONEYCOMB_MR1",
            "HONEYCOMB_MR2", "ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH", "ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1", "JELLY_BEAN",
            "JELLY_BEAN", "JELLY_BEAN", "KITKAT", "KITKAT",
            "LOLLIPOOP", "LOLLIPOOP_MR1", "MARSHMALLOW", "NOUGAT",
            "NOUGAT", "OREO", "OREO", "ANDROID P"};
    int index = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT - 1;
    osName = index < mapper.length ? mapper[index] : "UNKNOWN_VERSION";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer provides better (full) names for Marshmallow on, while also remaining future-proof if you don't update your app when a new version comes out (the best of both worlds.) The list of version names comes from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES).

```
String versionName =
        Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields()[Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + 1].getName();
String[] versionNames = new String[]{
        "ANDROID BASE", "ANDROID BASE 1.1", "CUPCAKE", "DONUT",
        "ECLAIR", "ECLAIR_0_1", "ECLAIR_MR1", "FROYO", "GINGERBREAD",
        "GINGERBREAD_MR1", "HONEYCOMB", "HONEYCOMB_MR1", "HONEYCOMB_MR2",
        "ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH", "ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1",
        "JELLY_BEAN", "JELLY_BEAN_MR1", "JELLY_BEAN_MR2", "KITKAT", "KITKAT_WATCH",
        "LOLLIPOP", "LOLLIPOP_MR1", "MARSHMALLOW", "NOUGAT", "OREO", "OREO_MR1"
};
int nameIndex = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT - 1;
if (nameIndex < versionNames.length) {
    versionName = versionNames[nameIndex];
}
```

Obviously this is derivative of the answers of others. In my experience, people don't like it when you try to edit an existing answer to improve it, hence my creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Build.VERSION.SDK; is return correct result but SDK is deprecated  as of API 16: Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean).so it will show like as w

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for `Xamarin.Android` the solution is simply:

```
Build.VERSION.SdkInt.ToString();
```

Pretty simple.

The reason is `SdkInt` is mapped to Android's `SDK_INT`:

```
[Register("SDK_INT", ApiSince = 4)]
public static BuildVersionCodes SdkInt
{
  get
  {
    return (BuildVersionCodes) Build.VERSION._members.StaticFields.GetInt32Value("SDK_INT.I");
  }
}
```

Which maps to an enum, and in C# when an enum `ToString` is called, the name (as opposed to the value) of the enum is returned instead:

```
 public enum BuildVersionCodes
  {
    [IntDefinition("Android.OS.Build.VERSION_CODES.Base", JniField = "android/os/Build$VERSION_CODES.BASE")] Base = 1,
    [IntDefinition("Android.OS.Build.VERSION_CODES.Base11", JniField = "android/os/Build$VERSION_CODES.BASE_1_1")] Base11 = 2,
    [IntDefinition("Android.OS.Build.VERSION_CODES.Cupcake", JniField = "android/os/Build$VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE")] Cupcake = 3,
 ...
```

Answer (score -4):

You can try following function.

```
 public String AndroidOSName() {
    String os = Build.VERSION.SDK;
    System.out.println("here is my os" + " " + os);
    if (os.equals("23")) {
        return "Marshmallow";
    } else if (os.equals("21")) {
        return "Lollipop";
    } else if (os.equals("22")) {
        return "LOLLIPOP_MR1";
    } else if (os.equals("20")) {
        return "KitKat";
    } else if (os.equals("19")) {
        return "KitKat";
    } else if (os.equals("18")) {
        return "Jelly Bean";
    } else if (os.equals("17")) {

        return "Jelly Bean";
    } else if (os.equals("16")) {
        return "Jelly Bean";
    } else if (os.equals("15")) {
        return "Ice Cream Sandwich";
    } else if (os.equals("14")) {
        return "Ice Cream Sandwich";
    } else if (os.equals("13")) {
        return "Honeycomb";
    } else if (os.equals("12")) {
        return "Honeycomb";
    } else if (os.equals("11")) {
        return "Honeycomb";
    } else if (os.equals("10")) {
        return "Gingerbread";
    } else if (os.equals("9")) {
        return "Froyo";
    } else if (os.equals("8")) {
        return "Froyo";
    } else {
        return "Not Found";
    }

}
```

Comment: Please note if you want to promote your own website or blog, **you must disclose your affiliation in the answer**. Otherwise, your answer may be flagged as spam. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).