# How to get the codename of android os version

Tags: android, api

I have retrieved the android version by String androidVersion = Build.VERSION.RELEASE

Now i want that if my version is 4.0 i should get IceCreamSandwich instead of 4.0 in a string variable at runtime.Please help if there is any API for codename. Thanks in advance.
My sample code is:

```
     String androidVersion = Build.VERSION.RELEASE.toString();
     String androidName = "";
     String and = "4.1.2";
        if(androidVersion == and)
        {
        androidName = "JellyBeans";
        }
    else
    {
        androidName = "Not Having any name";

    }
```

On debugging i m unable to enter the if loop and it is going in else. I don't Know what is the issue. May be the version i m getting and string i m passing to compare are not matching. Thanks in advance.

Comment: create `enum` based on this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android:how to find the android version name programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547818/androidhow-to-find-the-android-version-name-programmatically)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
public String getSDKCodeName(){
    String codeName = "";
        Field[] fields = Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            String fieldName = field.getName();
            int fieldValue = -1;

            try {
                fieldValue = field.getInt(new Object());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (fieldValue == Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
                codeName = fieldName;
            }
        }
    return codeName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to get the codename from android.
One easy way is to use

```
private Field[] fields;
fields = Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields();
fields[Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + 1].getName()
```

But this is not stable and caused me a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptioin` crash in production for few devices.

Manually creating a method to return the codename is very stable for me even in production.

```
String codeName = getVersionCode(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT)

private String getVersionCode(int code){
    switch (code){
      case 0:{
        return "BASE";
      }
      case 1:{
        return "BASE_1_1";
      }
      case 2:{
        return "CUPCAKE";
      }
      case 3:{
        return "CUR_DEVELOPMENT";
      }
      case 4:{
        return "DONUT";
      }
      case 5:{
        return "ECLAIR";
      }
      case 6:{
        return "ECLAIR_0_1";
      }
      case 7:{
        return "ECLAIR_MR1";
      }
      case 8:{
        return "FROYO";
      }
      case 9:{
        return "GINGERBREAD";
      }
      case 10:{
        return "GINGERBREAD_MR1";
      }
      case 11:{
        return "HONEYCOMB";
      }
      case 12:{
        return "HONEYCOMB_MR1";
      }
      case 13:{
        return "HONEYCOMB_MR2";
      }
      case 14:{
        return "ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH";
      }
      case 15:{
        return "ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1";
      }
      case 16:{
        return "JELLY_BEAN";
      }
      case 17:{
        return "JELLY_BEAN_MR1";
      }
      case 18:{
        return "JELLY_BEAN_MR2";
      }
      case 19:{
        return "KITKAT";
      }
      case 20:{
        return "KITKAT_WATCH";
      }
      case 21:{
        return "L";
      }
      case 22:{
        return "LOLLIPOP";
      }
      case 23:{
        return "LOLLIPOP_MR1";
      }
      case 24:{
        return "MARSHMALLOW";
      }
      case 25:{
        return "NOUGAT";
      }
      case 26:{
        return "OREO";
      }
      case 27:{
        return "OREO";
      }
      case 28:{
        return "PIE";
      }
      case 29:{
        return "Q";
      }
      case 30:{
        return "R";
      }
      default: {
        return "Android";
      }
    }

}
```