# Android programming how to Translate a number

Tags: android

In my app I am trying to display the Android version of the users current device as a textview however I have used the os.build.version.sdk and when I use that only the sdk code shows e.g 17 for Android 4.0.4 and I was trying get the Android version to show so is there a way to make an if or else statement to change the 17 into 4.0.4 at runtime. I have attached my java class below.

```
{
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    tv.setText(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK);
}
```

Comment: You could make a utility method that does the translation when given a VERSION.SDK.

Comment: Here is a good answer by Kevin Grant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13258693/488489

Answer (score 1):

To display the Android release number, I would suggest to use android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html

```
{
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    tv.setText(android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use VERSION.RELEASE field instead.

```
tv.setText(android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE + "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
tv.setText(String.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE));
```