# How to get version of android (4.1.1, 4.4.2,...) in Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5, android-version

I would like to get the version of the Android device. 
In Java it is android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE, how is it in Delphi?

Comment: possibly duplicate question...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547818/androidhow-to-find-the-android-version-name-programmatically

Comment: not really, i need it for Delphi XE5

Comment: See the Samples\MobileCodeSnippets\Delphi\DeviceInfo project, which not only shows the build (eg., 4.1.2) but the common name ("Ice Cream Sandwich MR1") and device name ("Samsung Galaxy S3") as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`System.SysUtils.TOSVersion`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.SysUtils.TOSVersion) record to get information about the operating system on which your application runs.

```
  TOSVersion = record
  public type
    TArchitecture = (arIntelX86, arIntelX64, arARM32);
    TPlatform = (pfWindows, pfMacOS, pfiOS, pfAndroid, pfWinRT, pfLinux);
  public const
    AllArchitectures = [arIntelX86, arIntelX64, arARM32];
    AllPlatforms = [pfWindows, pfMacOS, pfiOS, pfAndroid, pfWinRT, pfLinux];
  private
    class var FArchitecture: TArchitecture;
    class var FBuild: Integer;
    class var FMajor: Integer;
    class var FMinor: Integer;
    class var FName: string;
    class var FPlatform: TPlatform;
    class var FServicePackMajor: Integer;
    class var FServicePackMinor: Integer;
    class constructor Create;
  public
    class function Check(AMajor: Integer): Boolean; overload; static; inline;
    class function Check(AMajor, AMinor: Integer): Boolean; overload; static; inline;
    class function Check(AMajor, AMinor, AServicePackMajor: Integer): Boolean; overload; static; inline;
    class function ToString: string; static;
    class property Architecture: TArchitecture read FArchitecture;
    class property Build: Integer read FBuild;
    class property Major: Integer read FMajor;
    class property Minor: Integer read FMinor;
    class property Name: string read FName;
    class property Platform: TPlatform read FPlatform;
    class property ServicePackMajor: Integer read FServicePackMajor;
    class property ServicePackMinor: Integer read FServicePackMinor;
  end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the code

```
if TOSVersion.Check(4, 2) then
```

It will be true if Android OS version is 4.2.2 (API 17) or higher.