# How to get android OS version?

Tags: android, operating-system

I want to get android os version on my device.

first I try use **`BUILD.VERSION.RELEASE`** and **`BUILD.VERSION.SDK_INT`**

the release is **`6.0.1`**  sdk_int is **`23`**

but I want to get **`MARSHMALLOW`** text.

how to get android os version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android:how to find the android version name programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547818/androidhow-to-find-the-android-version-name-programmatically)

Comment: did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build.VERSION_CODES field name have the OS name so you can use Java Reflection (`java.lang.reflect.Field`) to get the field name.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

```
    Field[] fields = Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields();
    String osName = fields[Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + 1].getName();
    Log.d("TEST", osName);
```

Sample Log (`Note`: M is for Marshmallow)

```
07-18 20:09:08.198 3606-3606/test.atry D/TEST: M
```