# Get Android OS fork name

Tags: android

There are different forks of Android, such as [OxygenOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OxygenOS) or [LineageOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LineageOS).

In an Android app, is it possible to determine the Android fork the app is running on? I would normally suspect such information to be available via `android.os.Build`), but I can't find anything there. Am I missing something?

Please note that I'm *not* asking for the [version names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547818/androidhow-to-find-the-android-version-name-programmatically) such as Oreo, Pie, etc. I'm asking about the name of the fork, such as Lineage.

Comment: Forks.  They're forks of the Android OS.  ANd there's no way to tell, usually on purpose.  People really don't want apps to change behavior because they're on a fork of the OS.

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan; I updated the wording on my question accordingly. If you'd create an answer with the same content, I'll gladly accept it :)