# How to revert FastScroller android framework commit, and implement in listfragment?

Tags: android, android-listfragment, fastscroll

I have a listfragment with a fastscroller, which is not functioning correctly.

According to one of the answers here: [Fast scroll thumb disappears while scrolling AlphabetIndexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780792/fast-scroll-thumb-disappears-while-scrolling-alphabetindexer), there is a commit in the android framework causing issues with FastScroller.java (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/32c3a6929af9d63de3bf45a61be6e1a4bde136d3)

I'd like to copy the FastScroller.java code to my own project, manually revert the commit and implement the changed 'Fast Scroller' into my own listfragment.

Currently I use the fastscroller by implementing the following:

```
  ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
.
.
.
```

And I have a sectionIndexer further on.

How do I implement the custom FastScroller.java, when the only reference to the FastScroller is `lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that simple as copying the class from android source. It has a lot of dependences and copying is very hard or even impossible to achieve. Here you have an example implementation: https://github.com/nolanlawson/CustomFastScrollViewDemo

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Thanks for the link though, despite several Google searches, I never came across this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a regular `Fragment`, but having a list contained within it?

It could be that the `ListFragment` implementation isn't doing exactly what you want, but the standard `Fragment` implementation, with you putting a `ListView` in the layout might work differently.

Comment: I did try this, it seems that the problem persists!