# Android -how do I access device information like Android version of the device in my app?

Tags: android, permissions, device

In my app, I have an email button that uses an intent to open gmail app. How do I access the Android device version and the device model to include it in the body of the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the api info you can use below code.

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
   // Do something for froyo and above versions
} else{
   // do something for phones running an SDK before froyo
}
```

and for device maker information use below one

```
 String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;
 String deviceMan = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
```

will find more info on system properties here [Official doc - Build](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)