# How to get the specific OS version in android?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I need to give different functionalities for OS version > 4.4.2 and OS versions <= 4.4.2 .

When I used android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES for that purpose it is giving me the code corresponding to KITKAT for all versions of 4.4,4.4.1,4.4.2,4.4.3 . So how can I specifically differentiate between OS version 4.4.2 and 4.4.3?

Comment: String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Build.VERSION.RELEASE field for this, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically) thread for specifics. However, I advise you to use the .VERSION_CODES field wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE` if it's fit your needs.

Source : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html

You have `String RELEASE` which will be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
String myVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE; // e.g. myVersion := "1.6"
int sdkVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT; // e.g. sdkVersion := 8;
```

Source: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328719/getting-device-os-version-in-android-programmatically)

Comment: Wtf...  show a number incorrect .... example : I have to  minSdkVersion 15 and show 19 ....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that'll help you a bit:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion > 11){
    //your code here
}
```

More information about API:
[API's](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels)