# How I can check android version of device? (ionic 2,3)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

for android 4.2.2, ionic app shows white screen.
I want to know if the device had this version of android, app would show a message and would notify that this version of android is not supported.
is it possible?

Comment: did u mean that device OS version? like LOLIPOP is 5.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting device os version in Android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328719/getting-device-os-version-in-android-programmatically)

Comment: i want to know android version of devices that instal my app

Comment: for ionic please

Comment: I already posted an answer below to check version in Ionic framework only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I founded this solution:

```
  let platformVersion = platform.versions();
  if (platformVersion.android) {
    let androidV = platformVersion.android.num;
    console.log(androidV);
    if (androidV < 4.4) {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        message:  'Please update android ...'
      });
      alert.present();

      // or push a single page for this error:
      //this.nav.setRoot(ErrorPage);
    }
  }
```

for show this message in android device with version older than 4.4 we must be install this:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

for more information visit this link:

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html