# Show API version in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there any way to show an API version over emulator's screen? I know, it is written in window title, but for evidence it should better be written over wallpapers.

Comment: emulator's screen?means what? you want to android api version on emulator home screen?

Comment: If you mean showing it programmatically via the app, then have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/7328719/1225532

Comment: @HemantParmar, yes, you are right, draw it over home screen. Like in virtual desktops.