# I want to get the version of android by adobe air

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, android-version

I want to get the version of android by adobe air.
I searched the question,but not result.
So,if somebody kwows,please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is a duplicate of
[How can I detect the Android OS version in Adobe AIR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293236/how-can-i-detect-the-android-os-version-in-adobe-air)

How about Capabilities.os ?