# FragmentActivity on Android 1.5

Tags: android, compatibility, fragment

I have included android.support.v4.jar in my libs, but is still not compatible with 1.5. How can I achieve it?

logs:
E/AndroidRuntime(800): java.lang.VerifyError: android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its Supported **Minimum API level : 4** . **Android 1.6**

Look [Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) for More Details.

Look Here the Market Share of Android Versions.

```
Android SDK version table for Septmber 4 2012.

Android SDK version      Current market share   
1.5 (Cupcake)               0.1 %       
1.6 (Donut)                 0.1 %       
2.1 (Eclair)                4.0 %   
2.2 (Froyo)                 13.1 %      
2.3 (Gingerbread)           49.7 %      
3.0-3.2 (Honeycomb)         1.8 %       
4.0.x (ICS)                 28.5 %      
4.1 (Jelly Bean)            2.6 %
```

Comment: android.support.v4.jar, I should have see it "v4", But I hope there is a way.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) states:

> *Minimum API level supported*: **4**

API 4, of course, is Android 1.6 Donut. There is also a support library that is only compatible with v13 (Honeycomb 3.2) and up.

It is definitely worth nothing that it is almost unnecessary to support Android 1.5 at this time. [Only 0.2%](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) of devices run it (that's 2 in every 1,000 downloads) as of the writing of this post. And the demographic of that 0.2% will probably be largely A) developers and B) people who don't use a whole lot of apps, as they're more likely to stick to older technology.

So, you have three options:

1. Bump up your `minSdkVersion` to 4, and scrap support for 3 (1.5).
2. Use a [version check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365/android-get-version-of-system) to see if the version is 4+. (I don't recommend this. It gets very unmaintainable.)
3. Don't use anything from the support library. (Again, this seems silly, to scrap functionality over loss of 2/1,000 users.)

Answer (score 1):

Fragments not supported in Android 1.5. Minimum API level for using Fragments is 4.