# How to detect Android version of device running app?

Tags: android, mapping

I am using [MapsForge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/) and everything is ok. My problem is that old android devices are not supportiing Bidi (bidirectional) text. Persian names of street in older devices are incorrect but in new android versions are ok. I want to detect the android version of device to decide to run my custom (and simple) Bidi or not. Any idea?

Comment: I think the answer of this question will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365/android-get-version-of-system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String `Build.VERSION.RELEASE` will give you the user-visible version string (i.e 1.5, 1.6, 2.0), while `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` will give you a value from Build.VERSION_CODES that would be better to use if you want to compare against it programatically.

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

buf.append("VERSION.RELEASE {"+Build.VERSION.RELEASE+"}");
buf.append("\\nVERSION.INCREMENTAL {"+Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL+"}");
buf.append("\\nVERSION.SDK {"+Build.VERSION.SDK+"}");
buf.append("\\nBOARD {"+Build.BOARD+"}");
buf.append("\\nBRAND {"+Build.BRAND+"}");
buf.append("\\nDEVICE {"+Build.DEVICE+"}");
buf.append("\\nFINGERPRINT {"+Build.FINGERPRINT+"}");
buf.append("\\nHOST {"+Build.HOST+"}");
buf.append("\\nID {"+Build.ID+"}");

Log.d("build",buf.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

`android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK`

`Build.VERSION.RELEASE` //give you the actual numbers of your version; 2.3.3 or 2.2