# how to get Android platform code-names like Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-version

In my application I want to show the Android OS code name of the device. 
i.e. I want to get the android OS code names like `Honeycomb` or `Gingerbread` pragmatically at run time from device.

Is there any way to get that codename sting itself? I want’s to show that name in one of the screens in my app.

I can compare like this and hardcode the string.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT==Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {

    CodeName=”GINGERBREAD”

 } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT==Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){

    CodeName=”Honeycom”
 }
```

But if tomorrow new version released then I’ve to change the code again. That’s why I am looking for some why to get the code name string itself instead of getting version number.

So can anyone suggest some way to get the device's OS code name like we get the OS version number?

Comment: check this link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365/android-get-version-of-system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API in Android documentation to return the String of code name for you. You can obtain only VERSION NUMBER like 2.3, which you can show to users.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
enum Codenames
{
    BASE, BASE_1,
    CUPCAKE, 
    DONUT, 
    ECLAIR, ECLAIR_MR1, ECLAIR_MR2, 
    FROYO,
    GINGERBREAD, GINGERBREAD_MR1, 
    HONEYCOMB, HONEYCOMB_MR1, HONEYCOMB_MR2,
    ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH, ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1,
    JELLY_BEAN;

    public static Codenames getCodename()
    {
        int api = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        switch (api) {
        case 1:

            return BASE;
        case 2:

            return BASE_1;
        case 3:

            return CUPCAKE;
        case 4:

            return DONUT;
        case 5:

            return ECLAIR;
        case 6:

            return ECLAIR_MR1;
        case 7:

            return ECLAIR_MR2;
        case 8:

            return FROYO;
        case 9:

            return GINGERBREAD;
        case 10:

            return GINGERBREAD_MR1;
        case 11:

            return HONEYCOMB;
        case 12:

            return HONEYCOMB_MR1;
        case 13:

            return HONEYCOMB_MR2;
        case 14:

            return ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH;
        case 15:

            return ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1;
        case 16:

            return JELLY_BEAN;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

};
```

and then do

```
Codenames c = Codenames.getCodename();
```

Comment: so here i've change Codenames enum if some new version release. i don't want's to do that. please check out my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use reflection ?

```
    String versionCodename = null;
    Field[] fields = Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        Field fld = fields[i];
        try {
            int val = fld.getInt(null);
            if (val == Build.VERSION.SDK_INT && fld.getName().length() > 1) {
                String fldName = fld.getName();
                versionCodename = fldName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + fldName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
                break;
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

```
  Field[] fields = Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields();

  String osName = fields[Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + 1].getName();

  Log.d("OsName",""+osName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this,simply change the `.GINGERBREAD` to whatever you want, ie. `.HONEYCOMB`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
     // do code for device before gingerbread
}
```

Also check here for more info - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html

Edit - to get the version number as an int, you do

```
int versionNumber = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

And then you can use

```
if (versionNumber == 2.3){
    //do code here
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get that codename sting itself? I wants to show that name in one of the screens in my app. 
I can compare like this and hardcode the string. 
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT==Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
     // do code for device before gingerbread
} 

But if tomorrow new version released then I’ve to change the code again. That’s why I am looking for some why to get the code name string itself instead of getting version number.

Answer (score -1):

the deprecated String `Build.VERSION.SDK` should work

Comment: That one returns the same as `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` (at least on KitKat)