# Code to be executed on Android app upgrade

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to execute some code when android app is upgraded.

I read one way is to store the version info in shared preference/db and then compare on application onCreate and execute your logic.
[Does onCreate in Application run on upgrading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333470/does-oncreate-in-application-run-on-upgrading)
[Android: How to reset FirstRun SharedPreferences when my app is updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726283/android-how-to-reset-firstrun-sharedpreferences-when-my-app-is-updated)

But since the post dates back to 2013. Was just wondering if any new better ways have emerged out .

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to reset FirstRun SharedPreferences when my app is updated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726283/android-how-to-reset-firstrun-sharedpreferences-when-my-app-is-updated)

Comment: well, mostly what is needed on to be executed on update is DB related, if this is your case, you can use onUpgrade() at your sqliteHelper, its fired when oldVersion!=newVersion (db version number) once everytime you change the db version number (automatically handled too)

Comment: thanks @Yazan for the reply...well i have some application/ui specific thing to execute

Comment: @njzk2 i have gone through the link as i mentioned in my questioned...but was looking for some other ways