# Check if device is running Android 4.3

Tags: android

I have an app which needs to do something differently on new Android 4.3 devices.
I was looking at using:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html#version-codes

To check the version is 4.3 however there does not seem to be a `Build.VERSION_CODES` for 4.3?

So how could I go about finding out if the device is running Android 4.3

Comment: this has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365/how-can-i-check-the-system-version-of-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To check the version is 4.3 however there does not seem to be a Build.VERSION_CODES for 4.3

Sure there is. [Android 4.3 is `JELLY_BEAN_MR2`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#JELLY_BEAN_MR2). Your build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse) will need to be set to API Level 18.

Answer (score 2):

This should get the job done.

```
android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE
```

***That will give you the actual numbers of your version; aka 2.3.3 or 2.2***.