# Checking software version for a phone having Android API version less than 10

Tags: android

I am currently using this code snippet to find the SW version in phones with recent API versions. However, this is not working for phones with old API versions.

Comment: What do you mean by "Checking software version for a phone"?? Do you want API version??

Comment: no not API version. The factory phone software version for the particular phone on which the app is running.

Comment: Your commands are specific to LG phones, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check [Version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) of your device you can use :

`android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`

For further knowledge, [Robby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3093391/2591002) will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Build` class to get information about the current build, extracted from system properties. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html