# Find out android runtime version

Tags: android, android-ndk, dalvik, android-runtime

Is there is was to find out what android runtime version is currently used?
For example, on android v4.4 you can swipe between dalvik and art and i want to find out this information in runtime.

10x.

Comment: Check `android.os.Build.VERSION`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365/how-can-i-check-the-system-version-of-android

Comment: I need to know NOT android version but android RUNTIME virtual machine. Art or Dalvik.

Comment: Given that ART was optional and hidden in developer mode for Kitkat 4.4 and REQUIRED in 5.0, Build.VERSION might be the only officially supported mechanism.

Comment: Okay, i find this: System.getProperty("java.vm.version")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`System.getProperty("java.vm.version")`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)) - If ART is used by the system, the returned value will be either "2.0.0" or higher, meaning major versions lower than 2 will be Dalvik. This piece of insight comes from *[Addressing Garbage Collection (GC) Issues](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art.html#GC_Migration)*
 section of best practices for Verifying App Behavior on the Android Runtime.

#### Code examples

```
// catch only version 2 and not higher
// false for Dalvik, true for current ART, false for any new runtimes
boolean isArt = System.getProperty("java.vm.version").startsWith("2.");

// catch version 2 and above
// false for Dalvik, true for current ART, true for any new runtimes
boolean isArt = false;
try {
    isArt = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("java.vm.version")
            .split(".")[0]) >= 2;
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // we suppress the exception and fall back to checking only for current ART
    isArt = System.getProperty("java.vm.version").startsWith("2.");
}
```

Comment: As the docs say the value is always going to be present, you can just use [`.startsWith("2.")`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) on it to catch "2.x.x". If you want to also catch higher versions, you gotta do at least some rough parsing.