# Way to differentiate android 4.4.4 and android 4.4.2 in code

Tags: android, sdk, android-version

I have just found out that, I have a piece of code which doesn't work on android 4.4.4 so I don't want to run that and I want to have a if else condition for it however when I try to check through the code it does not work, even I know because **android 4.4.4** and **android 4.4.2** both are of API 19.

My question is how to differentiate?

Comment: Probably all you need to know is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365/how-can-i-check-the-system-version-of-android

Comment: Are you sure it happens on 4.4.4 for every device? My guess would be your app crashes on certain manufacturer devices. Such as, they have specific Samsung-only crashes etc

Comment: What type of question it is?

Comment: @Androider so-called `duplicate question`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Its working.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code :

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){ }
```

However Build.VERSION.RELEASE will give the exact string!!

Comment: Varun Bhai....I have to check the Build.VERSION.Release to get it done cause 4.4.2 and 4.4.4 both are KitKat. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, basically look at the class Build.VERSION where you can find this info