# How to check that application is running (Android>5.1)?

Tags: android

The code below works successfully on Android 4.4, but since android 5.1 getRunningAppProcesses () return only own process. How can I check if the application is running on Android> 5.1?

```
static boolean isRun(Context context, String pkg_name) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (procInfos == null)
        return false;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++) {
        ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo proc = procInfos.get(i);
        if (proc.processName.equals(pkg_name))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What to use instead of getRunningAppProcesses () for Android 5.1 and above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check the system version of Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365/how-can-i-check-the-system-version-of-android)

Comment: The question is how to determine the list of running processes in Android 5.1 and above? What to use instead of getRunningAppProcesses()?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, an implementation issue, not a version check!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/**
     * Method checks if the app is in background or not
     */

```
  public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;
            }
        }

        return isInBackground;
    }
```

The issue was resolved by adding permission to AndroidManifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS" />
```

Comment: getRunningAppProcesses() return size=1 for Android 5.1 and above!

Comment: What u want to check can u explain in detail.

Comment: I want to check if the application with pkg_name is running. The code in my question does not work in Android 5.1. and higher

Comment: For your own app or other installed apps.

Comment: other installed apps, please look carefully my code

Comment: The issue was resolved by adding permission to AndroidManifest.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156343/discussion-between-akshay-chopde-and-andrew-efremov).