# Android - Notification when OS is updated

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to send a notification to restart my app when a new version of the OS is installed. Is there an option to set this type of notification?

Comment: What do you mean by restart your app after you get the notification?

Comment: for an initial setup after an update its needed that my app runs once. That the user doesn't forget that, I'd like to remind him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such notification available.

You could only run your app at start-up ([boot_complete](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)), [read the system version info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365/how-can-i-check-the-system-version-of-android) and compare it to the stored one.

If the info has changed do whatever you want in case the system has been updated.