# A code detects the android version and gives a custom toast msg

Tags: android

I'm beginner of android app development. I have an android app with dark mode in it and the dark mode does not work for android version below 8. So i want to add a code which detects the android version of the phone and gives a toast msg or disables the switch which toggles dark mode. So how can i make it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365/how-can-i-check-the-system-version-of-android

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Build.VERSION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) class

```
    val release = Build.VERSION.RELEASE  //Version 11
    val sdkVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  //30

    Toast.makeText(this, "Version:$release SDK:$sdkVersion",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```